# How to sum up the coordinates (tuples) between 2 lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, coordinates, list-comprehension

Input: List A and B, both are the same length and each list is a pair (x,y) of numbers.

Output: A list of pairs(x,y) in which the first element of the *i* *th* pair  is the sum of the first element of the *i th* pair in A and the first element of the *i th* pair in B.

Example:

```
A=[(1, 2), (10, 20)]

B=[(3, 4), (30, 40)]
```

Return:

```
[(4, 6), (40, 60)]
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

```
A=[(1,2),(10,20)]
B=[(3,4),(30,40)]
new_a = [(c+d, e+h) for (c, e), (d, h) in zip(A, B)]
```

Output:

```
[(4, 6), (40, 60)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner without `zip`:

```
A=[(1,2),(10,20)]
B=[(3,4),(30,40)]
result=map(lambda x, y: map(lambda i, j: i+j, x, y), A, B)
```

To see the result:

```
print([tuple(i) for i in result])
# --> [(4, 6), (40, 60)]
```